# How to setup and configure service fabric clusters?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am reading the docs about service fabric and was also interested to review how to setup a cluster with multiple VM's, but so far I can only guess based on the devclustersetup.ps1 / it's xml file, but I didn't see any docs on it which explains the various configurations and/or API's.
What I would need is how to set up a simple cluster, how to add/remove nodes, monitoring, setting up resource constraints per node etc so I can setup a sample cluster and test few things.

So far I've done these:

- installed VC runtime ( as web pi installer fails without it )
- installed service fabric and the SDK ( got the installer out of the web pi installers )
- tried to change the sample xml, adding multiple hosts, but then with that I ran into the IPv6 only issue in my setup ( see my other question ), so it didnt work out

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting up a multi-machine cluster is not supported at this time so you won't find any documentation explaining how to do it.

There will be a public preview of the service in Azure later this year and the platform will be available as part of Windows Server 2016 for on-premise deployments. As those options become available, there will be plenty of guidance explaining how to setup and manage your cluster.

**UPDATE: 2016-03-31**

Standalone installation on-prem or in another cloud is [now available in public preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server/) for Windows Server 2012 R2 and up.

Comment: It would have save me some time if this was explicitly mentioned in the docs.  Thanks for the info ! I was to excited about this to set it up in a lab :) will have to wait now. Will it support server nano as well? That would be very interesting

Comment: From: @AbhishekRam-MSFT: We are working on NanoServer support for Service Fabric.

Comment: Is multi-machine cluster now supported with GA? Thanks.

Comment: Any word on how to manually scale/add/remove nodes to/from an on premise- cluster ?

Answer (score 4):

We are working on NanoServer support for Service Fabric. (I am unable to respond to the comment asking about it because I apparently don't have enough points).